# dynamic html code through cs code (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, computer-science

I am trying to make a dynamic html code through the cs code by using src from a dataset. (every item in the dataset is a src of another picture).It's the first time i am trying to do something like this and it doesn't work, any tips would be helpful :)

**html code**:

```
 <asp:Literal ID="imageGallery" runat="server" />
```

**cs (c#) code**:

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = DAL.GetBestPics();
    imageGallery.Mode = LiteralMode.Encode;
    string divStart = @"<div class='more-products-holder'><ul>";
    imageGallery.Text += divStart;

    foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        string imageHTML = @"<li><a>
                       <img src='";
        string mid = @"" + item.ToString();
        string imageHTML2 = @"' /></a></li>";
        imageGallery.Text += imageHTML;
        imageGallery.Text += mid;
        imageGallery.Text += imageHTML2;

    }
    string divEnd = @"</ul></div>";
    imageGallery.Text += divEnd;

    this.Controls.Add(imageGallery);
```

Comment: First, thanks for the fast comments.Nope, only "bad picture" like the source isn't good or something like that

Comment: I guess the path returned by item.ToString() is not correct. Open the output html and try to browse to the path mention in the img SRC attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    ...
    string mid = @"" + item.ToString();
```

item is DataRow object.
you are suppose to refer to one of the field/column, like:

item["FieldName"].ToString();

Answer (score 1):

In your code you assign the `DataRoW as image Source not DataRow Value..`

```
string mid = @"" + item.ToString(); 

item.ToString() - > is a DataRow Not a DataRow Value
```

its output was like this `<img src='System.Data.DataRow' />`

you need to change that like below

```
item["imageSrc"].ToString() - > it returns DataRow Value
```

you  must assign a field name to that like below

```
string mid = @"" + item["ImageSRC"].ToString();
```

its output was like this `<img src='sam.jpg' />`

Answer (score 0):

What about using stringbuilder class

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<div class='more-products-holder'><ul>");
        foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            sb.Append("<li><a><img src='" + item.ToString() + "'");
            sb.Append("' /></a></li>");

        }

       sb.Append("</ul></div>");
       imageGallery.Text = sb.ToString();
```